# ¿Cómo añadir color a los tag de HTML en un archivo de JavaScript?

Tags: vscode

¿Cómo darle color tanto a los tag de CSS y HTML en los archivos de JS?

Pude que se autocomplete pero no logro darle color en vez de que quede
como si fuese el color de un comentario.

¿Hay alguna forma nativa de habilitar o algún plugin?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Traducción de [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49174781/13419694) de Stackoverflow:

Podes usar la extensión [**es6-string-html**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html).

**Nota**: Tenés que agregar un comentario con el lenguaje en frente del string multi línea.

[image: Antes y después]